# How can i select this button and click it?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

how can i select this button from list element using selenium and click it?
this the html

```html
<li class="ml1 sel">
    <a href="#__about.htm" id="about_page" onclick="return menuClick(this);" class="T sel">
        <span>about us</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

**I have tried to use `xpath` `css selector` `id` and `class name`**
but always get error `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element:`

Is there anyone who can help me Please!

Comment: Check if the `Element` is in an `iframe`. If not, post the code you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

you might be able to use the `find_element_by_partial_link_text` or `find_element_by_link_text` functions.

Try using this link for an idea on how to use it. [Link](https://www.guru99.com/locate-by-link-text-partial-link-text.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 ways to click in Selenium.

I will use this xpath

```
//span[contains(text(), 'about us')]//parent::a[@id='about_page']
```

**Code trial 1 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'about us')]//parent::a[@id='about_page']").click()
```

**Code trial 2 :**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), 'about us')]//parent::a[@id='about_page']"))).click()
```

**Code trial 3 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'about us')]//parent::a[@id='about_page']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

**Code trial 4 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'about us')]//parent::a[@id='about_page']")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click().perform()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```